# Does "reading" a flash drive make it wear out or is it just "writing" that damages it?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I read online that writing to a drive wears it out quicker but does say, connecting a Kingston dual Micro USB stick to my TV's USB port to play video files from the drive  damage the drive?

Also,  can the TV somehow corrupt the files on the USB?

Comment: Reading could theoretically wear out a drive.  Explained in an answer here: http://superuser.com/a/981864/364367

Comment: more than likely, your tv will fail before the flash drive does.

Answer (score 0):

re your title -  both,  - and it can handle more reads than writes. You can get stats on how many reads it can take and how many writes it can take. Good to back it up. In theory some rogue or bad software on the TV could write something on some media plugged into it, but it has probably never happened before. If a computer has a bad power supply then it can potentially damage components, so in theory a TV built badly could break a usb stick but you'd be hard pressed to find any example somebody has proven has happened though it could even in practise. In practise it wouldn't write i don't think

Comment: Where can I get the stats?

Comment: @verve i'm sure i remember seeing them in the spec for a transcend flash  device.. IIRC flash devices can cope with more reads than writes.  But I can't see it in the specs looking at ssds now. Maybe higher capacity ones can handle so many reads/writes that they don't mention it anymore. And it was more of an issue with lower capacity things like usb sticks..

Comment: @verve maybe more of an issue with sd cards too as well as usbs  e.g. discussed here  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=21281   I understand that sd cards use flash memory too.  They're generally lower capacity than ssds. Maybe SD cards are more likely to include read/write  figures for how much they can take in the spec.